# extracting dates from SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem where I am supposed to extract row creation date for each row and be part of a large report.With SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) i can view record creation dates but i can not convert,extract that data and user it somewhere else. I'm getting an error message which says "`ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number`

```
ORA-06512: at "SYS.SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP", line 1"
```

The query i wrote was as follows:

```
*insert into MEMBER_CREATION_DATE(NATIONAL_ID,CHECKNO,CREATION_DATE)
select NATIONAL_ID,CHECKNO,trunc(scn_to_timestamp(ora_rowscn)) from MEMBER*
```

Answer (score 3):

Your clue is `ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number`

What it means is that the `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` is not able to get the `ORA_ROWSCN` because the record is no longer part of the `UNDO` data. The `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` which is the timestamp associated to that System Change Number is too old, therefore you get the error.

You can check the oldest available `SCN` number in database by this query:

```
select min(SCN) min_scn from sys.smon_scn_time;
```

As Oracle states:

> The association between an `SCN` and a timestamp when the `SCN` is generated is remembered by the database for a limited period of time. This period is the maximum of the auto-tuned undo retention period, if the database runs in the Automatic Undo Management mode, and the retention times of all flashback archives in the database, but no less than 120 hours. The time for the association to become obsolete elapses only when the database is open. An error is returned if the `SCN` specified for the argument to `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` is too old.